# C# element not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am unable to click login form element below site:

> http://www.w-trading.co.kr/member/login.php?

I try:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='memberId']")).SendKeys("my_id");
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("memberId")).SendKeys("my_id");
```

but each code occur error.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your watching.

I'm using Selenium in C#.

Comment: What are the errors that you are seeing in each case?

Comment: Are you sure the page is loaded when you executing click action? If not you have to wait until the page loads. Better share the error you get for this code

Answer (score 1):

Do something more advance.
Use a while that will wait for element.enabled to be true
Inside the while do a try catch, in this try catch you will be asking if element enabled = true

The you do the click and then the send keys

Comment: You really should add a code sample to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

1. `driver.FindElement(By.Id("memberID")).click();`
2. then `driver.FindElement(By.Id("memberID")).sendKeys("Text");`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 instances of the "memberId" Id attribute on the page. You need to interact with the second one.

Try this:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/descendant::input[@id='memberId'][2]")).SendKeys("my_id");`